# Native vs Polyfilled Shadow DOM

Tags: polymer, shadow-dom

I am working on a project in which I am constructing a graph with several nodes and edges using Polymer and web components. I am using an underlying library which is developed in-house by my company which is not based on web components. This library contains functions for creating nodes, initializing graph etc.I have created a custom element called graph which would interact with the library. Following is the declaration of this element:

```
<polymer-element name="cmp-graph" attributes="canvas" constructor="CMPGraph">

<template>  
      <div id="graph_win_placeholder">
        <div id="graph_win" class="canvas">
            <div id="graph_canvas" class="graph-area">
            </div>
        </div>            
      </div>
</template>

</polymer-element>
```

In my Javascript code of the element, I call a function in the library to initialize the graph. This function call needs a handle to the canvas div (the div with id="graph_canvas"). So I pass this.$.graph_canvas as a parameter while making the function call. But the library throws an exception since it is expecting a native version of the div and instead gets a wrapped one since this.$.graph_canvas corresponds to the wrapped version of the div.

I was experimenting different solutions and passing shadow=native as a parameter in the query string while loading my application worked.

But now the problem is, my application can run only on Chrome, Canary and Opera since other browsers do not have the native support for Shadow DOM. Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This was asked on polymer-dev with some followup: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/polymer-dev/twfdXBpT1cM/SF93Dyj5qcAJ

Comment: What exception is thrown?

Comment: Without further information about your in-house library this question is unanswerable.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no architectural issue in your library, as a last resort you can 
upwrap node just before usage. 
Remember to check if Polyfill is present on page or not, otherwise below code will break on chrome.

```
if(typeof ShadowDOMPolyFill !== undefined)
{
    var unwrappedNode = ShadowDOMPolyFill.unwrap(node);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Abhinav.. I actually used the same approach. I had to unwrap the node when Polyfill is being used and it solved the problem